# Fixing X axis on a histogram

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram but have some outliers and it currently looks like: [image: this]

Using the `xlim = c(-1,1)` condition just gives me [image: this]

Is there anyway to get a more detailed view of the values between -1 and 1.

Thanks

Comment: check out the `breaks` arguments when you do `?hist`

Comment: some examples:
    `hist(runif(100), breaks = 10)`, 
    `hist(runif(100), breaks = 20)`, 
    `hist(runif(100), breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.2))`